# How can I avoid a VLOOKUP Error that occurs when I delete a name?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, formula

The pictures used are only from an example sheet! My basic problem is that I have a list called Assignment in which names appear (dropdown list). For Location (in the assignment sheet) I use the following formula: `=IF(C2<>"",VLOOKUP(C2,'Input Data'!C$3:D$7,2,FALSE),"")`

[image: Assignment]

These names are assigned certain values, they are in the same line. The names are defined in a worksheet called Input Data!

[image: Input Data]

If I now delete a name like Green, John from the Input Data worksheet, then I get the following error in another worksheet (Evaluation). (More than 40 people have access to this worksheet and randomly delete names)In this evaluation worksheet the values are evaluated by the following formula:

[image: Evaluation]
[image: Project Overview]

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF((IF($B$2="dontcare",1,REGEXMATCH(Assignment!$E$3:$E$577,$B$2 &"*")))*(IF($B$3="dontcare",1,(Assignment!$E$3:$E$577=$B$3)))*(IF($B$4="dontcare",1,(Assignment!$D$3:$D$577=$B$4)))*(IF($B$5="dontcare",1,(Assignment!$F$3:$F$577=$B$5)))*(IF($B$6="dontcare",1,(Assignment!$B$3:$B$577=$B$6))),(Assignment!S$3:S$577)))), 1, 1)
```

The following error appears in the evaluation sheet:
Error:
During the evaluation of VLOOKUP the value "Green, John" was not found.

[image: ERROR]

How can I avoid this error? Is it possible to avoid this error with a macro that deletes Names from assignment sheet that are not in the Input data sheet? Do you have any ideas for a code?Maybe a Formula or perhaps a Macro?
example sheet with explanation: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OU_95Lhf6p0ju2TLlz8xmTegHpzTYu4DW0_X57mObBc/edit#gid=1763280488

Comment: I guess a macro would be the best solution!

Comment: I found very difficult to understand the situation with so many tables and formulas. Could you please provide a sample Sheet so there is a clearer of example of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The only was for poeple to test this is to actually see the error in action but nobody is going to waste the time building a sheet just to test this, so provide a sample sheet that people can use to test. "but the value is not permanent, it is variable" how is this variable set / selected?

Comment: I am not really able to reconstruct a sample sheet, the basic problem is just, that when a name gets deleted from the Input Data sheet, a VLOOKUP Error occurs like I described it

Comment: example sheet with explanation: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OU_95Lhf6p0ju2TLlz8xmTegHpzTYu4DW0_X57mObBc/edit#gid=1763280488

Comment: So my only question is, how to write a script that deletes specific lines in the assignment list, if a line occurs with a name like Green, John, that is not in the input data list. short version: Example! Assignment sheet: line 7 Green, John -> check if Green, John is in sheet Input Data in row C! If Green, John is not in Input Data row C -> delete line 7 Green, John in Assignment! .... That is basically my question! –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want to do is make sure that rows are deleted in a sheet when there are incorrect values you could try something like this in **Apps Script**:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var spreadsheet = e.source;
  
  var assignment = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Assignment");
  var assignmentRange = assignment.getDataRange();
  var assignmentNames = assignment.getRange(3, 2, assignmentRange.getNumRows());
  
  var inputData = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Input Data");
  var inputDataRange = inputData.getDataRange();
  
  var i = 1;
  while(assignmentNames.getNumRows() > i){
    var currentCell = assignmentNames.getCell(i, 1);
    var txtFinder = inputDataRange.createTextFinder(currentCell.getValue());
    txtFinder.matchEntireCell(true);
    if(!txtFinder.findNext()){
      assignment.deleteRow(currentCell.getRow())
    }else{
      // We are only steping when no elements have been deleted
      // Otherwise we would skip rows due to shifting in row deletion
      i++;
    }
  }
}
```

---

### Explanation

`onEdit` is a special function name in Apps Script that would execute every time it's [parent sheet is modified](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events).

After that we retrieve the spreadsheet from the event object

```js
  var spreadsheet = e.source;
```

---

Now we get the relevant range in the `Assignment` sheet. Look at the usage of [`getDataRange` documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange) to avoid retrieving unnecessary cell values. And from that range we actually get the specific column we are interested on.

```
  var assignment = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Assignment");
  var assignmentRange = assignment.getDataRange();
  var assignmentNames = assignment.getRange(3, 2, assignmentRange.getNumRows());
```

---

Now we do the same for the other sheet(`Input Data`):

```
  var inputData = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Input Data");
  var inputDataRange = inputData.getDataRange();
```

**Note**: Here I'm not getting a specified column because I assume that the full name will not repeat in any other column. But if you want you could get the specified range as I have done at `Assignment`.

---

After that we want to look for specific values in the `Assignment` range that don't exist in the `Input Data` sheet,  you should try the [TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder).

For every name in Assignment [you should create a `TextFinder`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createTextFinder(String)). I have also forced to make a [whole cell match](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#matchEntireCell(Boolean)).

```js
  var i = 1;
  while(assignmentNames.getNumRows() > i){
    var currentCell = assignmentNames.getCell(i, 1);
    var txtFinder = inputDataRange.createTextFinder(currentCell.getValue());
    txtFinder.matchEntireCell(true);
```

If `txtFinder` finds a value the  [`findNext()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createtextfinderfindtext) will evaluate to `true`. In the other hand when the `txtFinder` does not find a value it will be `null` and evaluated to false.

```js
    if(!txtFinder.findNext()){
      assignment.deleteRow(currentCell.getRow())
    }else{
      // We are only stepping forward when no elements have been deleted
      // Otherwise we would skip rows due to shifting in row deletion
      i++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: the name can be John too, it can be any name... but if the name is not in the sheet Input Data, the whole row with the not occuring name has to be deleted in Input Data! THis is a possible solution:

Comment: ```function checkName() {


  var s1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Input Data");
  var col1 = s1.getRange("C3:C").getValues();

  var s2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Assignment");
  var col2 = s2.getRange("C4:C").getValues();

  for (var i=col2.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    var found = false;
    for (var j=0; j<col1.length; j++) {
       if (col1[j][0] == col2[i][0]) {
         found = true;
         break;
       }
    }

    if (!found) {
      s2.deleteRow(i+4);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I changed my answer to solve your problem. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: It works fine! The only problem I have now is that the macro recognizes no upper and lower case letters. in my list are Full Names like "Michael, Ballack" in "Assignment" and for example "Michael, BALLACK" in "Input Data" (which is the same name) and in this case it deletes the content, but it shouldn't! Can you help me with that "upper and lower case letters" problem?

Comment: If you are using the solution I provided you can just add [`matchCase()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder.html#matchCase(Boolean)) right below the `matchEntireCell()` method. If you are comparing strings directly you could just [make them lowercase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) to make sure are working.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59900660/creating-a-data-history-with-excel-vba-using-lastrow-time-stamp-and-workbook-sh could you please help me here?